# How to use auto_html gem in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to do a blog using rails 4.2 and I want users to be able to embed images and videos in their posts. What's a good way to do it. I tried using the youtube_it gem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. install the gem: gem 'auto_html', '~>1.6.4'
2. bundle install

Then in your Post.rb - model

```
auto_html_for :content do
    image
    youtube(width: 400, height: 250, autoplay: true)
    link target: '_blank', rel: 'nofollow'
    simple_format
  end
end
```

This should get you going.